# Как сделать, чтоб по умолчанию был класс open, а при первом клике блок сворачивался?

Tags: jquery

Есть функция, которая по идеи должна по умолчанию добавить класс open к главному блоку wrap_bl. А по нажатию на title_bl блок сворачивается, а класс open удаляется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Или задать класс заранее в html:

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  $(document).on('click', '.title_bl', function() {
    var $jot = $(this).parents('.wrap_bl');
    $jot.toggleClass('open');
    if ($jot.hasClass('open')) {
      $('.content_bl').slideDown();
    } else {
      $('.content_bl').slideUp();
    }

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap_bl open">
  <div class="hed_title_bl">
    <span class="title_bl">Название</span>
  </div>
  <ul class="content_bl">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Название 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Название 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Название 3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Название 4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Название 5</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Или присваивать скриптом:

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  $('.wrap_bl').addClass('open');

  $(document).on('click', '.title_bl', function() {
    var $jot = $(this).parents('.wrap_bl');
    $jot.toggleClass('open');
    if ($jot.hasClass('open')) {
      $('.content_bl').slideDown();
    } else {
      $('.content_bl').slideUp();
    }

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap_bl">
  <div class="hed_title_bl">
    <span class="title_bl">Название</span>
  </div>
  <ul class="content_bl">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Название 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Название 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Название 3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Название 4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Название 5</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Два варианта:

1. При загрузке страницы стриггерить событие `$('.title_bl').trigger('click');`
2. Почему бы сразу в html не повесить класс `open`?

Comment: "Почему бы сразу в html не повесить класс" там немного не удобно. Но я даже и об этом не подумал, а вариант вполне рабочий. Спасибо!